# Measure the battery level on ns-3

Tags: ns-3

I am trying to build a MANET on NS-3. Is it feasible to measure the batteries of the wireless nodes and calculate the energy consumption? Can I use other standards, like Bluetooth, Zigbee, LoRA again by measuring the battery? So for example start the simulation using WiFi/Bluetooth/Zigbee/LoRA with the nodes having 100% battery, and with the use of trnasmition/receiving packets, to measure when the battery goes lower..70%, 30% ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ns-3 has a [module](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/dir_6dbe3a74fddfb865e2d1b322bca63f2b.html) for working with energy consumption, it's in `src/energy`. Already having some [power consumption models](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/group__energy.html) implemented:

- [Rakhmatov Vrudhula non-linear battery model](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_rv_battery_model.html)
- [Model a generic Lithium Ion Battery](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/classns3_1_1_li_ion_energy_source.html)
- Linear model

You can look at some examples of how to implement the templates in `src/energy/examples`. Recalling that ns-3 has no proprietary technology modules like ZigBee and Bluetooth, it currently implements a common communications module [LR-WPAN](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/group__lr-wpan.html) based on the IEEE 802.15.4 standard.

There is also an unofficial [LoRaWAN](https://github.com/signetlabdei/lorawan) module that works on ns-3.